# Why was there only one Iron Giant?

Tags: the-iron-giant

In the animated film "[The Iron Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Giant)", a kid befriends an amnesiac giant robot. The robot has amnesia due to a dent in its head sustained upon landing, but we later learn that it is really

> a Martian death machine loaded with energy weapons and such. The irony of the film is that the Iron Giant really IS part of an alien invasion, confirming the semi-paranoid fears of the townspeople and military forces. It is only through his friendship with the boy that these fears are circumvented.

My question, however, is **why would there be only ONE Iron Giant?** I can only assume that he was an advance scout or that his landing was an accident. Otherwise, it would only make sense for there to be numerous robots instead of a single one.

Has anyone involved with the film, or any of the related materials (comics, novels, book it's based on, etc.) answered this question?

Comment: There was a deleted scene where, no, the Giant was just one of a very very large invasion force in places distant.  I do not, however, have a source, and whether it's canon...?

Comment: @Radhil - This scene? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSjqF5tR894&feature=youtu.be&t=53s

Comment: @Valorum - I'd actually not seen it before, but it looks right.

Comment: @Radhil - I've never seen the film. I've heard good things about it.

Comment: @Valorum It's an amazing film, I need to watch it again.

Comment: @Hashim - Three years later I've still not seen it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was a scene deleted from the original release that covered more of the Giant's background as part of a dream he had.

Basically, no, **the Iron Giant was not alone**.  The deleted scene shows the Giant dreaming in Dean's junkyard, and it's visions show up on Dean's TV while he's drowsing.  It's dream shows that at some point in the past, it was part of a large, destructive invasion force, used as a weapon against others. They possibly even destroyed planets, as one is shown being ripped to pieces by energy beams.

Here's a bit from the DVD extras where Brad Bird and others discuss the removal of the scene, and it also shows the storyboard:

Apparently, a new Signature Edition of the film has added this scene back in, and can be seen fully animated courtesy of [@Valorum's find in comments](https://youtu.be/OSjqF5tR894).

As for why the Giant is alone now, the only piece of evidence we have to go on is the giant dent in his giant head, and there are too many possible stories for how he could have been damaged.

Comment: I wouldn't have know that the new release has different material if not for this.